# Deletando dados automaticamente depois de determinado tempo

Tags: php, mysql

Exemplo:

Tenho uma tabela com três campos: id int pk, nome varchar, categoria int.

O campo categoria poderá receber 2 valores: 1 e 2;
Por default sempre quando um dado for inserido ele terá uma categoria 1.

O que eu quero é o seguinte. 
Quando um dado for inserido, ele tem até 10 dias para ser alterado para 2. Caso contrário, o mesmo será excluído.

Tem alguma maneira de eu fazer isto?

Grato!

Comment: Você é administrador do banco?

Comment: @Ricardo Sim, eu sou.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usa [create-event.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html)

Ficaria mais ou menos [assim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6560655/3517631):

Criar a procedure:

```js
CREATE PROCEDURE delete_rows_links()
    BEGIN
       DELETE FROM minhatabela WHERE categoria = 1 AND data < CURRENT_DATE()-10;
     END
```

```js
CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 SECOND (vc escolhe)
    DO
      CALL delete_rows_links();
```

No link tem mais definições onde vc pode aprender mais.

Comment: Ricardo essa `delete_rows_links` é uma _procedure_? Sei que não é o ponto principal da resposta, mas se tu colocar o código de exemplo dela agregaria muito valor a sua resposta.

Comment: Coloquei um modelo lá, mas ele teria que ajudar em relação ao melhor nome para ele, colocar uma coluna data na tabela para controlar a data de inclusão, fazer seus próprios ajustes, mas já deu uma melhorada sim.

Answer (score 3):

Grave a data inicial e final que ele inseriu a categoria e deixe o servidor programado para verificar se está entre o período de 10 dias, se não passou ele remove o dado.

Você pode programar no servidor um script com crontab da seguinte maneira,  ele irá pingar seu script de acordo com o período que você programar, e neste script, você faz a verificação da data:

Será executado:

- Uma vez ao ano: `0 0 1 1 *`.
- A cada mês: `0 0 1 * *`.
- Uma vez por semana: `0 0 * * 0`.
- Uma vez por dia:  `0 0 * * *`.
- A cada hora: `0 * * * *`.

0 0 * * 0 php /caminho/completo/do/seuscript.php

**o seuscript:**

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "senha", "banco");

/* verifica se está conectado */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "DELETE FROM evento
          WHERE status =1
          AND now() NOT BETWEEN data_inicial AND data_final";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
```

E para gravar o período de 10 dias:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "senha", "banco");

/* verifica se está conectado */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$dataInicial = new DateTime();
$dataFinal   = new DateTime('+10 days');


$query = "INSERT INTO evento (nome, categoria, status, data_inicial, data_final) VALUES(?,null, 1, ?, ?) ";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $nome, $dataInicial, $dataFinal);
```